# Actual area from polygons is either under- or overestimated when extracting raster values - any solutions?

Tags: arcgis-desktop, modelbuilder, clip, resampling, extract-by-mask

I am trying to use ModelBuilder to iterate through sets of polygons to overlay on top of two rasters and extract the total area of each value from each raster, but am having issues with the estimated area from rasters and the actual area from polygons matching up.

I have tried

1. clip (from Spatial Analyst toolbox for rasters),
2. extract by mask, and
3. tabulate area,

but all give me the same results in terms of over- or underestimating the actual area of the polygon.  I think because the cell size of the rasters is subjectively huge (~1500m), smaller polygons might have a more difficult time with it (there is huge breadth in the size of polygons).  I tried resampling the raster to a cell size of 500, but it only makes the area issue worse.

Any advice?

Comment: Resample and ser environment variable cee size equal to it.